# How to fix current page does not display true? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

Why my current page in Page Control does not show correct output?

Page 1 and Page 2 display in one dot? Images here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/498ap.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/41kdg.png

Last page is page 6 display in dot 5th, doesn't last dot? Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP9u1.png

My code here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

let totalPages = 6
let sampleBGColors: Array<UIColor> = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.lightGrayColor()]    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    configureScrollView()
    configurePageControl()
}

func configureScrollView() {
    // Enable paging.
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

    // Set the following flag values.
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = false

    // Set the scrollview content size.
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(totalPages), scrollView.frame.size.height)

    // Set self as the delegate of the scrollview.
    scrollView.delegate = self

    // Load the TestView view from the TestView.xib file and configure it properly.
    for i in 0 ..< totalPages {
        // Load the TestView view.
        let testView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TestView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        // Set its frame and the background color.
        testView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
        testView.backgroundColor = sampleBGColors[i]

        // Set the proper message to the test view's label.
        let label = testView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label.text = "Page #\(i + 1)"

        // Add the test view as a subview to the scrollview.
        scrollView.addSubview(testView)
    }
}


func configurePageControl() {
    // Set the total pages to the page control.
    pageControl.numberOfPages = totalPages

    // Set the initial page.
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
}


// MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate method implementation

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Calculate the new page index depending on the content offset.
    let currentPage = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width);

    // Set the new page index to the page control.
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}


// MARK: IBAction method implementation

@IBAction func changePage(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Calculate the frame that should scroll to based on the page control current page.
    var newFrame = scrollView.frame
    newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.size.width * CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage)
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(newFrame, animated: true)

}
```

Please help me! Thank you.

Sorry for my English is bad.

Comment: Page control start with page 0, and number of pages = 6 , at index 5  in array it is gray colour , you need to change numberOfPage

Answer (score 0):

Change the **pageControl.currentPage** in UIScrollViewDelegate's implemention **scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation** and **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating**, and I improved the calculation with scrollView's width, not screen's width:

```
// MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate method implementation
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Calculate the new page index depending on the content offset.
    let currentPage = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    // Set the new page index to the page control.
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView)
}
```